# C# modify specific node XML and delete all node with same attribute

Tags: c#, xml

Well I got XML like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<!--Alert notes-->
<Aletrs>
    <Alert>
        <Name>Counter</Name>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </Alert>
    <Alert>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>02:46:10 - Alert ID.1 nr.1 Camera1 - photo</Name>
        <Value>Capture/Images/Camera1_snapshoot_nr1-2014-03-02_02-46-10.png</Value>
    </Alert>
    <Alert>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Name>02:46:11 - Alert ID.1 nr.2 Camera1 - photo</Name>
        <Value>Capture/Images/Camera1_snapshoot_nr2-2014-03-02_02-46-11.png</Value>
    </Alert>
</Alerts>
```

At first I need help in modify number in Value in `Counter` name Alert node, I got the code how to get this value but I failed to modify it into changing value and save modified XML:

```
string index = (from xml2 in dailyXML.Descendants("Alert")
                    where xml2.Element("Name").Value == "Counter"
                    select xml2.Element("Value").Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Also I need help in code deleting all "Alert" nodes which have same value in `< ID>..< /ID>`

Comment: First `Alert` node does not have id. Is it OK? Also it would be very nice to see your expected resulting xml

Comment: Yes, it keep only number which are used for alerts ID, for example if there are alerts with ID = 1, Counter value would be 1. If would be another alert with next ID = 2, Counter = 2.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get what you mean

Answer (score 0):

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);

/*1*/
var value = xDoc.Descendants("Alert")
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.Element("Name").Value == "Counter")
            .Element("Value");
value.Value = "1";


/*2*/
foreach(var alert in xDoc.Descendants("Alert")
                         .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Element("ID")))
{
    alert.Skip(1).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Remove());
}
```

Comment: Hey, first one works perfetly! unfortunatley second dont.. it didnt deleted all nodes with same value in <ID>, also where do declarate which ID number he have to delete?

Comment: @DanielSz It works for the example xml you posted. If you test it with a different one, then post it.